# Runtime error, shape is invalid for input

Tags: pytorch

i am trying to get the input and output information of a network. When debugging, i got this error, Runtime, shape ‘[-1, 400]’ is invalid for input of size 384. I tried different values, but can’t find the correct value. Is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16*5*5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

```
input_shape = (3, 21,21)
        dummy_input = torch.randn(6,*input_shape)
        graph = torch.jit._get_trace_graph(model,  args=dummy_input, _force_outplace=False, _return_inputs_states=False)
```

Error message:

```
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 400]' is invalid for input of size 384
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the tensor after the convolutional layers is [6,16,2,2]. So you cannot reshape it to 16*5*5 before feeding them to the linear layers. You should change your network to the one given below if you want to use the same filter sizes as the original in the convolutional layers.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*2*2, 120) # changed the size
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16*2*2) # changed the size
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Comment: https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807